# Minimum Pumping Length.

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, finite-automata

What is the minimum pumping length of $(01)^*$

The solutions says 1, but can someone explain why that is? I understand this language accepts the empty string, but the minimum pumping length cannot be $0$. But, why is it 1? A general explanation of how to calculate the minimum pumping length would be much appreciated as well.

Thanks.

Comment: "The solution says 1." According to the definition in _Introduction to the theory of Computation_, Michael Sipser, exercise 1.55, **the minimum pumping length of $(01)^*$ is 2**.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the minimal DFA for $(01)^*$: it has three states(one garbage or dead state), so any non-empty word of the language must cause it to repeat a state and therefore can be pumped. The minimum length of a non-empty word of the language is $2$, so the minimum pumping length is at most $2$. Note, though, that the language contains no word of length $1$, so if $w$ is in the language, and $|w|\ge 1$, then automatically $|w|\ge 2$, and $w$ can be pumped. Thus, $1$ is also a pumping length for the language.

Comment: Based on that reasoning would the minimum pumping length for 1011 be 5, since the minimal dfa has 5 states.

Comment: @user283591: You mean for the one-word language $\{1011\}$? The minimum DFA actually has six states. However, the minimum pumping length is indeed $5$, since $1011$ cannot be pumped.

Comment: Oh, I thought the minimal dfa does not take into account the garbage state. 1->0->1->1->accept. Which, is 5.

Comment: @user283591: The definition of DFA to which I’m accustomed requires that every state have a transition out for each symbol of the alphabet, so there must be a garbage state. And the proof of the pumping lemma depends on the fact that inputs of a certain minimum length must lead to loops in the state path; for this language that requires a garbage state and an input length of at least $6$. The fact that the minimum pumping length is only $5$ comes from the fact that there is no word of length $5$ in the language.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Could you tell why the minimum pump length for {1001} is 5.Does _pumping length_ means the number of times pumped or is it the string length needed to pump a string?Can we say if we have a loop in state '1' it's minimum pumping length is 1 and if the loop is in state '2' it's MPL is 2 and so on turning to have MPL n for state 'n'.

Comment: @justin: It’s the minimum length with the property that every word of that length (or more) can be decomposed and pumped.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Can we say if we have a loop in state '1' it's minimum pumping length is 1 and if the loop is in state '2' it's MPL is 2 and so on turning to have MPL n for state 'n'?

Comment: @justin: The pumping length is a property of the DFA as a whole, not of individual states.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Yeah that's true.I meant to say a DFA with 1 state ,2states and n states.It's just a typo.Could you know answer the question in the previous comment.

Comment: @justin: Yes, the number of states in a **minimal** DFA for the language can be used as the pumping length.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Okay.Is this true for any **DFA**.For example consider a DFA that has 2 state and another DFA that also has 2 states.Let's consider that for the first DFA the _loop_ is in the first state and for the second DFA the _loop_ is in second state.Could we tell that both of the DFA's have the same minimum pumping length?

Comment: @justin: What do you mean by the loop being *at* a state? A loop in a two-state DFA can involve both states.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Oh sorry I meant to say _loop_ as the state at which **pumping** takes place.

Comment: @justin: It need not be the same state for each pumpable word. All you know is that if the word has at least as many characters as the DFA has states, it must repeat *some* state. Another word of that length might repeat a different state.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Can we say that a minimum pumping length is depended on the state where pumping takes place?Let's say that (using the previous comment) since the pumping takes place in state 1 it _might_ have minimum pumping length as 1 and for the second DFA it's(MPL) is _definitely_ 2?What confuses me is whether the place of pumping has an profound impact on MPL of the DFA.

Comment: @justin: You’re looking for something that just isn’t there. All that you can say for sure is that if the minimal DFA for a given regular language $L$ has $n$ states, then $n$ is a pumping length for $L$, and so is every larger integer. In a specific case it *may* happen that the language has a smaller pumping length, but it need not, and you need specific knowledge of the language in order to tell. And in a given DFA it’s quite possible that *any* state may be the first repeated state for at least one pumpable word in the associated language.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Can we have minimum pumping length as 1 for a DFA that has two states and the language **L** is $a^nb$ and the alphabet $\sum={a,b}$?

Comment: @justin: A minimal DFA for that language has $3$ states: you need a ‘garbage’ state.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Oops sorry for that and that's my fault.I meant to say 3 states but didn't think properly.I think that I'm really looking into pumping a string in the alphabet rather than pumping a string in the language.Am I?

Comment: @justin: The pumping lemma deals only with words that are in the language *and* are at least as long as the pumping length.

Comment: @Yeah that's very right.Your last comment changed my vision of pumping lemma.Now it's true that if your language **L** is $a$ and alphabet is $\sum={a}$ then the minimum pumping length should be 1 and as in the previous comment if the language **L** is $a^nb$ and alphabet $\sum={a,b}$ then the minimum pumping length would be 3 isn't it?

Comment: @justin: A minimal DFA for the language $\{a\}$ over the alphabet $\{a\}$ actually has three states, so we know that $3$ is a pumping length. In fact it turns out that $2$ also works, simply because no word of the language has length $2$. In general, if $L$ is a finite language, and $\ell$ is the length of the longest word of $L$, then $\ell+1$ is the minimum pumping length for $L$. With a finite language you need to be sure that no word of the language can be pumped. In the case of $\{a^nb:n\in\Bbb N\}$, we again know that $3$ is a pumping length, since the minimal DFA has $3$ states, ...

Comment: ... but it turns out that $2$ also works: the only word of length $2$ in the language is $ab$, which can be pumped, since we can split it as $xyz$ with $x=\epsilon$, $y=a$, and $z=b$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Oh sorry I couldn't get your first sentence.Could you tell why they are three states? For language  $\{a\}$ I think we only need 2 states one is the _start_ state and other is _final_ state where if the symbol is $a$ go to the _final_ state and if the symbol is not $a$ remain in the _start_ state itself.From _final_ state if we have a symbol that is not $a$ again go back to the _start_ state.I couldn't get why would we need 3 states.If $a$ is our **string** I think that we can pump $a$ into ${aa,aaa,aaaa,..........}$ so since the _length_ of $a$ is 1 shouldn't the MPL be 1?

Comment: @justin: You need an initial state that is not an acceptor state, another state that is an acceptor state, and a third state as a garbage collector. If these are $q_0,q_1$, and $q_2$, the $a$-transitions are from $q_0$ to $q_1$, from $q_1$ to $q_2$, and from $q_2$ to $q_2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Could you tell why can't we make the initial state as a garbage state too.....?

Comment: @justin: Because we’ve already used up its $a$-transition: it goes to $q_1$. We can’t also have one from $q_0$ to $q_0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Since our alphabet is really $\sum={a,!a}$ altogether can't we have a transition $!a$ from $q_0$ to $q_0$?

Comment: @justin: What do you mean by $!a$? Since the alphabet is $\Sigma=\{a\}$ (*not* $\Sigma=a$), each state must have exactly one transition out, and that transition corresponds to reading an input of $a$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:How would we denote a symbol that isn't $a$?That's why I wrote it as $!a$.Do you mean to say that we can't use $!a$

Comment: @justin: There isn’t one here: the alphabet is $\{a\}$, so the only symbol that we need consider is $a$. But it doesn’t really matter: if there are other symbols in the alphabet besides $a$, you still need the same three states. The transitions for any symbol other than $a$ are from $q_0,q_1$, and $q_2$ to $q_2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Could you tell how would we denote other symbols in the alphabets besides $a$?It's true that we have to name any transition we define.

Comment: @justin: If there are just a few, I’d name them all, with transitions like $$q_0\overset{b,c,d}\longrightarrow q_2\;.$$ Alternatively, you could define a modification of the usual diagram notation by saying that a transition labelled with a subset of the alphabet is governed by each symbol in that subset; then you could label a transition with $\Sigma\setminus\{a\}$ if it was governed by every symbol other than $a$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Okay if that's the case is there problem now in having two states?

Comment: @justin: Yes: exactly the same problem. You need an $a$-transition from $q_0$ to $q_1$, and the garbage state needs an $a$-transition to itself, so you can’t use $q_0$ as the garbage state.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Oh that's right my fault.I haven't think about a scenario where we get an $a$ after reaching the garbage state.Sorry for that.Now can we have the MPL as 1 since as I said earlier we can pump $a$ into $aa.aaa.aaaa,...........$ and the length of string $a$ is 1?

Comment: @justin: If the language is $\{a\}$, the minimum pumping length is $2$; if the language is $\{a^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, then the minimum pumping length is $1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Do you mean to say that you can't pump with MPL as 1 if the language is $\{a\}$ because after reading $a$ you can't pump nothing?Or is there any other reason why we can pump $aa$ and we can't pump $a$?Could you help me.

Comment: @justin: If $L$ is regular, $the word $a$ is in $L$, and $1$ is a pumping length for $L$, then $a$ can be pumped to show that $a^n\in L$ for each $n\ge 0$. Thus, the language $\{a\}$ cannot have $1$ as pumping length. It *can* have $2$ as pumping length, simply because no words of $L$ have length $\ge 2$, so no words of $L$ are pumpable. A finite language cannot have a pumpable word: pumping always produces infinitely many words of the language.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Could you format the previous comment propery since it's hard to read.

Comment: @justin: Sorry about that. If $L$ is regular, the word $a$ is in $L$, and $1$ is a pumping length for $L$, then $a$ can be pumped to show that $a^n\in L$ for each $n\ge 0$. Thus, the language $\{a\}$ cannot have $1$ as a pumping length. (The rest was okay.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Could you tell what made language $\{a\}$ not to have $1$ as pumping length.Is **pumping length** made for _languages_ or for _strings_?

Comment: @justin: I just did: if it had pumping length $1$, the word $a$ would be long enough to qualify for the pumping lemma. Thus, it could be decomposed as $xyz$, where $|xy|\le 1$ and $|y|\ge 1$. Obviously this means that $x=z=\epsilon$ and $y=a$. But then $y^k\in L$ for all $k\ge 0$, meaning that $a^k\in L$ for all $k\ge 0$. This is false, and $L$ **is** regular, so $1$ can’t be a pumping length for $L$. \\ It is languages that have pumping lengths, not individual strings.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Yeah that's right.Could you tell whether we could pump the initial part of the string $x$ instead of pumping the middle part of the string $y$?

Comment: @justin: Look at the statement of the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages): it’s the middle part that is guaranteed to be pumpable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Okay.Is there any issues in pumping the initial part?Could you tell why pumping lemma stricly enforces that "you have to pump the middle part".

Comment: @justin: Because that’s what the proof of the pumping lemma gives you. If you’ve not worked through that proof carefully, you really should do so: once you understand the proof, which is not a very difficult one, you’ll see exactly why the pumping lemma is stated the way it is.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Yeah I checked the proof in [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) but it only tells about the pigeonhole principle.I would like to know if we could start pumping in the initial state itself.Does this change the proof of pumping lemma?

Comment: @justin: It may happen for a particular pumpable word that the $x$ part is empty; that happens when the the first repeated state in the path through the DFA governed by that word is the initial state. But there may be no words in the language with this property, and even if there is one, there may well be others that don’t have it. I strongly suspect that you don’t really understand the proof: if you did, this would be obvious. (And you wouldn’t say that ‘it only tells about the the pigeonhole principle’: the argument using the pigeonhole principle is the core of the proof.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Oh sorry I didn't meant to tell that $x$ part is empty.I meant to make the $z$ part empty and make the $x$ part to pump(or have a loop) and having the $y$ part as a string(or strings).Could you tell whether this is an issue?For more it's here at [cs](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53780/confusion-in-pumping-lemma).

Comment: @justin: I think that you have some fundamental misunderstanding of the pumping lemma, because that question just doesn’t make sense. The statement of the pumping lemma is clear: there exists **some** decomposition of the word of the form $uvw$ that satisfies three conditions. These conditions are that $|uv|\le p$, $|v|\ge 1$, and $uv^kw\in L$ for all $k\ge 0$. Whatever you call the three pieces; the conditions say that the first two pieces together have length at most $p$, the middle piece is not empty, and if the middle piece is omitted or replaced by any number of copies of itself, the ...

Comment: ... resulting word is still in the language. **Shreesh**’s answer to your question over in CSSE is exactly right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Yes I could get that but I'm really looking why does pumping lemma imposes a condition that "only the middle piece could be repeated"?Why can't we repeat the initial piece?I'm really looking for the significance of _middle piece_ in pumping lemma.

Comment: @justin: Look at the proof: the first repeated state may not be the initial state. The only part that can be repeated is that part corresponding to the loop in traversing the state graph, and if that loop doesn’t start at the initial state, the part of the word that takes the DFA from the initial state to the first state of the loop won’t belong to the part that can be pumped.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:As you could see from this [dfa](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewlkq.jpg) a _loop_ is present in the initial state.Can we split this as $x=b$,$y=a$ and $z=\epsilon$ so that the string $bbba$ could be accepted by **pumping** the $x$ part.Could you give evidence if my claim is wrong.

Comment: @justin: With that DFA and the string $bbba$, you have $x=\epsilon$, $y=b$, and $z=ba$. (There are other possibilities, but that’s the most natural one.) You’re still pumping the middle part: it’s just that the initial part in this case happens to be empty.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Yeah that's very nice.Could you tell why it's the most _natural_ one?This is the answer I was really looking for.

Comment: @justin: Because when that DFA reads the input $bbba$, the very first repetition of states comes when the first $b$ returns it to the initial state. In this case it happens that we get other loops within the first $4$ inputs, but the proof only guarantees us one, and it’s simplest to take the first one.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Could you explain why we get other loops within the first 4 inputs.In my opinion if we read the input $bbba$ it would go to initial state($q_0$) three times and then it goes to $q2$ after reading $a$.It seems that it goes to the loop at the initial state($q_0$) three times.I couldn't get any other _loops_ while reading the input $bbba$.

Comment: @justin: You can treat the *second* transition from $q_0$ to itself as the loop, or the combination of the second and third. In the first case you get $x=b,y=b,z=ba$; in the second case, $x=b,y=b^2,z=a$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Couldn't $x=b^3$,$y=a$ and $z=\epsilon$ be a case too?Could you tell whether there is any issue regarding this case.

Comment: @justin: No, that’s not possible: the $a$ transition from $q_0$ to $q_2$ is not a loop. If you examine the proof of the pumping lemma, you’ll see that the $y$ part of the word **must** drive the DFA through a closed cycle. That’s precisely why you can pump that part of the word.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Yes I could get what you're trying to tell.Could you show an example to prove that "we can't split the input $bbba$ into $x=b^3$,$y=a$ and $z=\epsilon$".As we look into the [dfa](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewlkq.jpg) we could see that this dfa would receive $ba,bba,bbba,bbbba,bbbb.............a$ etc.I couldn't get the issue in **pumping** the $x$ part i.e $b$.

Comment: @justin: You can’t split it that way because if you could, $b^3a^k$ would be in the language for every $k\ge 0$. But in fact $bbbaaa$ is *not* in the language.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:That's for sure.I would like to know whether $b^ka$ would be in the language for every $k\ge0$ for the given [dfa](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewlkq.jpg).

Comment: @justin: Yes, it would: every one of those words drives the DFA to $q_2$, which is an acceptor state. Every word of the form $b^ka^2$ is also in the language, since every one of those words drives it to $q_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Okay.Then could you tell why can't we split $b^ka$ as $x=b$,$y=a$ and $z=\epsilon$.Whether this _split_ would change the way in which the **pumping** in finite automata takes place?

Comment: @justin: I already did, in two different ways. First, pumping $a$ gives you some words that aren’t accepted by the DFA. Secondly, an input of $a$ in state $q_2$ does not drive the DFA through a closed cycle. \\ If it’s at all possible, you need to sit down with someone who can work with you in a more concentrated fashion. I can’t tell what it is, but it’s clear that you have some fundamental misconception that’s getting in the way of your understanding the pumping lemma, and we’re not really getting anywhere. I hate to do this, but I’m going to withdraw from the discussion: I simply don’t ...

Comment: ... know what I could say to make matters clearer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Okay.Sorry for the inconvenience I made for you but thanks for your kindness and cooperation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Could you please show an _example_ to show that if 'state $q2$ doesn't drive the DFA through a closed cycle we can't accept the string'.